# How to create a pdf print out using Visual basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf

I read a webpage ([link](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/visual-basic-tutorial-pdf)). It shows how to create a pdf file using VB. However, VB shows many errors after I follow the webpage to create my own pdf program. For example

mjwPDF.cls(1) : error BC30188: Declaration expected.

I am not sure whether it is a VB version difference problem. Does anyone know another pdf creator which is free?

Thanks

Comment: What has this to do with VBA? Also the link that you gave is for VB6.

Comment: Sorry that I am new to VB. I just read the link to understand the difference between VB and VBA.